# gitlab, includes in other include file?

Tags: ansible, gitlab, yaml

I'm wondering if it  is possible to includes a file into other includes? for example: let's say I have a file A.yml and File B.yml and gitlab-ci.yml, I want to include B in A then A in gitlab-ci.yml like this :

```
#in file A.yml
include:
  - 'B.yml'
#in Gitlab-ci.yml
include:
  - 'A.yml'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, and called nested includes (available since v11.9)

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/includes.html#use-nested-includes

Comment: thank you I'll test it , it's what I was looking for .

Answer (score 1):

The short answer - yes, you can, by using the [`include`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#include) keyword. E.g.:

```yaml
include:
    file: '.my-external-file.yml'
```

Comment: even in another include file ? so in : ` .my-external-file.yml` have this :
`include:
    file: '.my-external-file_2.yml'
`
thank you for your quick answers

Comment: @AitZaid haven't tested this myself, but IIRC, it should work